# TensorFlow core debug; missing debug symbols

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to learn TensorFlow's internals by stepping from its CIFAR-10 model training's python code into its core C++ code.
Using Eclipse+PyDev for step by step debugging of the python code works great, but I can't find how to step into the C++ code of the TensorFlow core. 
I tried using Eclipse CDT to build the C++ code in a separate project, and attach the debugger to the python process running `cifar10_train.py` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507911/debug-c-library-from-python-ctypes), but the symbols are never loaded and (obviously) deferred breakpoints are never hit.

**Background and setup:**

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, installed the TensorFlow code from sources as described [here](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#installing_from_sources) and my CDT project uses a Makefile containing

`bazel build -c dbg //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer`.

Comment: You may need to re-build TensorFlow from source using "--compilation_mode dbg" in order to include the symbols

Comment: If I understand bazel's user manual correctly, your suggestion is equivalent to the "-c dbg" flag I used...

Comment: yes, equivalent. Hm...I wonder if the problem is that all the TensorFlow C symbols are not in "python" binary, but instead in .so files that are dynamically loaded and used through SWIG. Here's a link I found that looked a bit relevant -- http://library.tebyan.net/en/Viewer/Text/164572/330

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able to work around the problem in a different way and can step into the C++ code. Will post an answer for this question.

Answer (score 6):

TensorFlow loads a library called `_pywrap_tensorflow.so` that includes its C API (as defined in `tensorflow/tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc` ).

In my case the library loaded during runtime was located in
`~/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so`
but the library that was built from the local source code was located in `~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_<username>/dbb3c677efbf9967e464a5c6a1e69337/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-dbg/bin/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so`.

Copying the locally built library over the loaded library, and attaching to the python process as defined in the question solved the problem.

Comment: after I replace with `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so`, I still can't get the debug symbol in core dump. Do you have any idea? My bazel build param is: `--config=opt --copt=-O2 --compilation_mode=dbg --strip=never --config=cuda --verbose_failures `