# Cannot set breakpoints in CDT and eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse (galileo) and the current version of CDT on Linux.  And I cannot set breakpoints!  It runs fun, debugs fine and stops in main...but double clicking in the left margin as I've done years ago with CDT now does not work! grrrrr...

Comment: Breakpoints still work for me in both galileo and helios.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Eclipse CDT ignore breakpoints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204282/why-does-eclipse-cdt-ignore-breakpoints)

Answer (score 3):

I had the aptana plugin installed to test debugging javascript.  I removed it and this symptom went away.  I think there is some evil interactions with CDT and Aptana
wcn